# 15/16 ips reel to reel tape speed

Tags: audio-recording

Have old 1/4" tapes from my father on 7" reels that were recorded at 15/16 ips and I am having difficulty finding a reel to reel that will play that slow and accept 7" reels.
Looking  for direction on what mono reel to reel machines can play these/
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

They're known as logging recorders - often used to check broadcast over 24 hours, in case anything went wrong, or the station needed to check back on specific details. They were very low quality recordings, not really suitable for music.

Revox made a 15/16 ips-capable version of the A77, called the SLS. I've never seen one & have no idea where to start looking, they're going to be pretty rare. Revoxes take 10" reels, so 7" is going to be no problem, NAB hub or otherwise.

They're mentioned on http://www.reeltoreel.de/worldwide/A77Special.htm

Yay me… I shall put on my google-fu black belt ;)
I found a stereo one for sale at £600 https://picclick.co.uk/revox-a77-4-sls-twin-track-reel-to-reel-224130551011.html

You might try an audio restoration company for a one-off transfer, but I think these machines are going to be very few & far between these days.

Of course, if you have access to any reel to reel you could always try the long-shot of transferring at 7½ or even 15 ips at the highest bit-rate your DACs will do, then slowing it down. Those old logging machines were low-quality anyway, so you might salvage enough to be intelligible, for free.

Comment: Thanks!  Great response & info!!!